# What is the value of kCGWindowName?

Tags: cocoa, quartz-graphics

I am using Quartz through an FFI based on ffilib (that is Quartz is dynamically loaded). A call to `CGWindowListCopyWindowInfo` returns an `CFArray` of dictionaries containing information on windows. One interesting key is `kCGWindowName`, which can be used to get the name of a window.

In C one would include the approriate header file, but since I am using ffilib I need to know the value of `kCGWindowName`. According to Apple's documentation it is `CFStringRef`.

How can I obtain the value of `kCGWindowName`?

An attempt grepping for `kCGWindowName` in the header files gave no usable result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this...

```
CFArrayRef windowsInfo = CGWindowListCopyWindowInfo(listOptions, kCGNullWindowID); 

for (CFIndex idx=0; idx<CFArrayGetCount(windowsInfo); idx++) {
    CFDictionaryRef dict = CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(windowsInfo, idx);
    CFStringRef windowName = CFDictionaryGetValue(dict, kCGWindowName);
    NSString* nsWindowName = (NSString*)windowName;
}

CFRelease(windowsInfo);
```

Comment: OK, that's what you want. Well I couldn't find it either but I took a guess. I replaced kCGWindowName with CFSTR("kCGWindowName") in the code and it worked. So that's what it stands for! It must be defined like this... const kCGWindowName = "kCGWindowName". I hope that helps.

Comment: So simple! I should have guessed that. Next up is how to construct the CFString. Unfortunately CFSTR is macro and thus not available through the ffi. But I guess I can find CFSTR in a header file somewhere.

Comment: The easiest solution turns out to be `CFStringCreateWithCString`.